How to block/unblock access to certain IP/port using netsh portproxy?
I need to simulate connect/disconnect of an app to an ip:port.
I cannot change firewall rules as they are managed by IT only.
I must be careful to not kill the network interface as it is a remote machine (Citrix VDI).
I want to use netsh portproxy. My theory is that it would redirect remote ip:port to 127.0.0.1:port.. and if i change local port to something random, the app should lose the connection.
so i tried:
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=11111 connectaddress=somehostname.com connectport=11111
where 11111 is the actual port - the app stayed connect. when i deleted it and ran:
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=22222 connectaddress=somehostname.com connectport=11111
I expected the app to drop the connection but nothing changed. I thought i might have misunderstood what redirects to what so i tried
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=11111 connectaddress=somehostname.com connectport=22222
again - no change..
Whats the correct way to do it using netsh portproxy?


My theory is that it would redirect remote ip:port to 127.0.0.1:port

No, it works the opposite way.
Portproxy does not actually intercept any connections – rather, it works very much like an HTTP 'reverse proxy' or an SSH 'local tunnel', where it starts listening for connections on the listen address:port (using a standard TCP listener) and connects to the connect address:port on the proxy client's behalf. Hence the parameter names.
So the proxy only functions when programs explicitly connect to the listen address:port (127.0.0.1:port in this case). If they're connecting to anything else, they're bypassing the proxy.

Whats the correct way to do it using netsh portproxy?

There is no way to do it using netsh portproxy.

so i just need to configure the app for port 22222, then delete proxy in the middle of its use.. easy.
